# How to stop VS Code indenting oddly when moving block of code with alt-arrow

Tags: visual-studio-code

See https://youtu.be/mJDg4WnrsUo

When I move a block of code down it does this odd indenting whereby each move down a line also does an indent. When I move it up it doesn't show this behavior.

I can format the entire file afterwards, but is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Incidentally, I use vim bindings but I also tried disabling them and it didn't change this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by auto-indent. To disable it, set:

```
"editor.autoIndent": "keep"
```

From OP: Here's the screen where you do that, it is in 'settings' from the main menu:

[image]

However what you show should never happen so please [file a bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md) for your case